# Lock table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I use WPF/C# and in DataGrid bound to some entity collection I want the status column to have some defined background COLOR depending on its value (possible values are 1, 2, 3, 4, each value associated with one fixed color). Please, how to do that?

Best regards!

Comment: I think there are few semantic connections between the title and the contents of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look into styling the DataGrid rows and using a DataTrigger to set the colors.